# Error installing any package using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I am installing any package I get this error.

> npm ERR! code E500
>
> npm ERR! 500 Internal Server Error: jsdom@latest

What is happening with my npm?

Comment: can't you install any other packages ?

Comment: no, because appers the same error

Comment: are you bihind a proxy server ?

Comment: no, I do not use proxy server

Comment: What version of npm do you have installed? What operating system are you using? How did you install npm? Was it working before, or has it never worked for you?

Comment: I installed the version 5.4 and my SO is Ubuntu 16.04, but I deleted the npm and nodejs, I am installing again,

Comment: He worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Ok I Removed all, and I installed node v8.11.3 and npm 5.6.0, but in the terminal it suggest me that update npm at version last,but now show me this error

`npm i -g npm`

`npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY`

```
npm ERR! sha512-e38cCtJ0lEjLXXpc4twEfj8Xw5hDLolc2Py87ueWnUhJfZ8GA/5RVIeD+XbSr1+aVRGsRsdtLdzUNO63PvQJ1w== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-e38cCtJ0lEjLXXpc4twEfj8Xw5hDLolc2Py87ueWnUhJfZ8GA/5RVIeD+XbSr1+aVRGsRsdtLdzUNO63PvQJ1w== but got sha512-mtehl59WPxzYV2c2doa5MJ8+VJ7LI1VXWYPxyrfupTSGLZfzMrtGqxmi3nyTRj44+4zunOe0O2aNx3JLFUkiSA==. (5376652 bytes)
```

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
`npm ERR!     /home/haroldv22/.npm/_logs/2018-06-15T13_02_32_098Z-debug.log`